# Best way for login different app on the server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have 2 android app:  `ClientApp` and `CashierApp`. It different app's but bouth app's can login on my server. I need implement login functional for this applications. On server side I have one controller - `UserController` and 2 methods:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/user/login")
  public UserDto login(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    return userService.getUserWithAuth(userDto);
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "/cashier/login")
  public CashierDto loginCashier(@RequestBody CashierDto cashierDto) {
    return userService.geCashierWithAuth(cashierDto);
  }
```

I do not understand how to implement this correctly:

1. use different URLs and DTO models for each application(like now)
2. Create enum `UserType.USER, UserType.CASHIER` add it to one `UserDto` and use one endpoint(URL). Then pass `UserDto` to userService and split the login type by enam
3. some other way

in the first way I do not like that when a new application appears that needs to be authorized, you need to create a new URL, new method and etc.

in the second version I do not understand how I correctly login in the service(switch case???). And the fact that one model will contain an extra field

Comment: I would say that's about to you. Both ways are ok it just depends how many apps are you willing to use and if you want them to have similar path fields. If you really want to use the same method for both but with different params you should send the parametes with a json and choose what to do inside the method.

Comment: Use same URL and add ROLE variable to decide who i going to login.